# Three-column page setup: How to continue enumeration after \end{task} and reduce vertical space?

Tags: margins, enumitem, tasks

The code below creates a 3 column, enumerated math solution set within `\task` environment.

After Problem #8, the words **Multiply and simplify** are inserted independent of the enumeration. These words are forced flush left by `\end{tasks}` (h/t tex.stack member whose commented solution was deleted)

When I try to continue the enumerated problem set with `\begin{tasks} [style=enumerate](3)` 2 formatting problems result:

1. too much vertical space is added before the "Multiply and Simplify"
2. the enumeration restarts at #1 instead of continuing with #9.

[image]

Your assistance is deeply appreciated!

mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
       {}
       {Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Simplify.}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt{27}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #2
\task 
$3\sqrt{48}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #3
\task 
$5\sqrt{12}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #4
\task 
$\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
\bigskip
$=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #5
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #6
\task 
$2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(2a^2)(a^4)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #7
\task 
$3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #8
\task 
$5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #9
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
$=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}
\bigskip
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
% Prob #10
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
$=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @mico Thank you for the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the title using a three columns wide  unlabeled pseudo-task.

`\task!` makes items that span all columns.

The same was done to the first title to keep the alignment.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
{}
{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    \noindent 
    
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=1.5em, %<---------
    item-indent=2em,   %<---------
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=1em     %<----------
}
\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

    \begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](3)
        \task![]\textbf{Simplify.}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
        % Prob #1
        \task 
        $\sqrt{27}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #2
        \task 
        $3\sqrt{48}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #3
        \task 
        $5\sqrt{12}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #4
        \task 
        $\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
            \bigskip
            $=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #5
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #6
        \task 
        $2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(2a^2)(a^4)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #7
        \task 
        $3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #8
        \task 
        $5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #9
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            $=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}\bigskip
            
        \task![]\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}% added <<<<<<<<<<            
            
        % Prob #10
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            $=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
    \end{tasks}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant and sooo simple your solution! Fixed both problems with a single code line.  Many thanks! Checked as answer.  BTW, was ```\task!``` your only tweak to the code?

Comment: @Siuslaw Math Thank you for your feedback! Only the two titles were changed. (plus a `\bigskip`  before the second.

Comment: Would you happen to know why the ```\task![]\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}``` tweak produced this error: ```Package tasks Warning: The width of `label-width' is too small on line 163. Please set it at least to 19.4667pt.```  (code compiles to pdf with no prob...just curious why error popped up in log)

Comment: @Siuslaw Math Not related with `task!`. It was triggered by Prob #10 (label with two digits). Try  `label-width=1.8em,  item-indent=2.2em,`

Comment: Bam! Perfect fix. Thanks so much!